# Does this Diophantine inequality have any solutions for $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, diophantine-equations, wolfram-alpha

Does this Diophantine inequality have any solutions for $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$?

> $$p^2 q^2 \geq 3 p^2 q + 3p^2 + 3pq^2 + 3pq + 3p + 3q^2 + 3q + 3$$

I tried to use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28p%5E2%29%28q%5E2%29+%3E%3D+3%28p%5E2%29q+%2B+3%28p%5E2%29+%2B+3p%28q%5E2%29+%2B+3pq+%2B+3p+%2B+3q%5E2+%2B+3q+%2B+3), and it says that there are $11$ *possible* solutions, all of which have a negative $q$.

Can anybody here validate Wolfram Alpha's computation?  I am thinking that this may be another one of those instances where its existing numerical algorithm limits its capability to search the solution space.

(Postscript:  I was unable to see a **diophantine-inequality** tag, so feel free to remove the **diophantine-equations** tag if it is inappropriate.)

Comment: For the inequality as it currently stands, let $p=q=\text{big}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality as it currently stands has infinitely many solutions. For look for solutions with $p=q\ge 1$. Then each term on the right is $\le 3p^3$. There are $8$ of them, so the right-hand side is $\le 24p^3$.

The left-hand side is $p^4$, which is $\ge 24p^3$ if $p\ge 24$.

Comment: It may be a little easier to see if we divide both sides:  $$p^2 q^2 \ge 3 p^2 q + 3p^2 + 3pq^2 + 3pq + 3p + 3q^2 + 3q + 3$$ by $p^2 q^2$, giving the equivalent:  $$ 1 \ge 3(q^{-1} + q^{-2} + p^{-1} + p^{-1}q^{-1} + p^{-1}q^{-2} + p^{-2} + p^{-2}q^{-1} + p^{-2}q^{-2})$$ and ultimately:  $$ (1 + p^{-1} + p^{-2})(1 + q^{-1} + q^{-2}) \le \frac{4}{3}$$